# How to make a list of quoted strings from the string values of a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Begin with:

```
select my_col from test;
```

Out:

```
my_col
x
y
z
```

How can I change the output of the three rows into an output of a list of three quoted strings in PostgreSQL, so that it looks like the following?

Out:

```
'x','y','z'
```

If I run `string_agg(my_val, ''',''')`, I get

Out:

```
x','y','z
```

If I run quote_literal() on top of this output, I get:

Out:

```
'x'',''y'',''z'
```

I need this list of quoted strings as an input for the argument of a function (stored procedure). The function works by passing the `'x','y','z'` as the argument by hand. Therefore, it is all just about the missing leading and trailing quote.

*Side remark, not for the question: it would then get read into the function as `variadic _v text[]` so that I can check for its values in the function with `where t.v = any(_v)`.*

Comment: *I need this list of quoted strings as an input for the parameter of a function (stored procedure).* : that would be suprising. A function typically takes a list of values as  input, not a string containing the aggregated values of the arguments.

Comment: @GMB I was aware of this even without your comment, wanted to fix it, now you saw it before I could get to it. I changed `parameter` to `argument`, I think that is the right wording here. (hopefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select string_agg('''' || my_val || '''', ',') my_val_agg
from test
```

That is: concatenate the quotes around the values *before* aggregating them - then all that is left is to add the `,` separator in between.

`''''` is there to produce a single quote. We can also use the POSIX syntax in Postgres:

```
select string_agg(E'\'' || my_val || E'\'', ',') my_val_agg
from test
```

Comment: Alternatively: `string_agg(format('%L', my_val), ',')` or `string_agg(quote_literal(my_val), ',')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Both work, the latter seems easiest to remember and to read, I took it.

Comment: This is not the core of this Q/A anymore: when I now take this list of quoted strings and copy its values by hand into the argument field, it works. But if I use the `(select string_agg...)` instead, it does not work. I guess the input cannot deal with the output, `(select...)` as a field. Could be a new question, but perhaps you know about how to change from a one-field output to a text[] output?

Comment: New question at [How to get a list of quoted strings from a string as the output of a SELECT query that has that list of quoted strings in it, but is of type string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734762/how-to-get-a-list-of-quoted-strings-from-a-string-as-the-output-of-a-select-quer).